# Opening multiple .xml files in excel with .xsl stylesheet

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a .xsl stylesheet that I use to open my .xml file in excel. This builds the tables I need and works fine for a single file. But I need to be able to open multiple .xml files and have them open in the same excel spreadsheet. I also need it to combine the tables that have the same tags from each .xml file. For example, if each .xml file has a buildingAddress tag, I would like to get each address from each separate file and display them in the same table in excel. What would be the easiest way to get these results? I am new to all of this so forgive my ignorance.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for the [document()](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/func_document.asp) function.

> The document() function is used to access nodes in an external XML document. The external XML document must be valid and parsable.
>
> One way to use this function is to look up data in an external document. For example we want to find the Celsius value from a Fahrenheit value and we refer to a document that contains some pre-computed results:

```
<xsl:value-of select="document('celsius.xml')/celsius/result[@value=$value]"/>
```